# Monitoring sensor usage on smartwatch with Tizen

Tags: .net-standard, tizen

I'm trying to write an app for a Samsung Galaxy Watch 3 that runs on Tizen (wearable 5.5).
The goal is to monitor other apps that use the various sensors so that I can display in real time which app uses what sensor.

I've gone for a .NET app, but depending on the possibility I could switch to webapp or native. The Tizen .NET API doesn't provide methods to retrieve sensor usage. My other idea was to try parsing the system log, as it contains PIDs of apps, "SENSOR" tags, and sensor info. If I could access it (according to the [documentation](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/error/system-logs/), the log is situated in `/dev/log_main`), I could easily determine which app uses what sensor and base my app on this.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to achieve my goal?
2. Is it possible to access the system log from my app? If yes, I assume I'll need root privileges?
3. From the previous question, is there currently an accessible and safe way of gaining root access? The watch I used belongs to my University.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to achieve it(both native and web).

> 2. Is it possible to access the system log from my app? If yes, I assume I'll need root privileges?
> 3. From the previous question, is there currently an accessible and safe way of gaining root access? The watch I used belongs to my University.

As far as I know, you can't get root privileges legally. also, logs are just information(it can be changed at any time by any reason), not the protocol promised with the Application programmer. So even if you can parse the log, it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: That's also the conclusion I came to. Indeed, parsing the log is not a viable solution as it probably raises security issues (if I can read and write in the log, what stops me from pretending to be another app?), it was just an idea. Thanks for your input :)